# Canvas Image. TranslateTransform loses the image in some cases

Tags: canvas, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, translate-animation

I have a Canvas with Image.

```
<Canvas
    x:Name="ImageCanvas"
    SizeChanged="Root_OnSizeChanged">
    <Canvas.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry
            x:Name="RootGeometry"/>
    </Canvas.Clip>

    <Image
        x:Name="Image"
        Source="{Binding TestData, Converter={StaticResource TestDataToBitmapConverter} }" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"

        ManipulationStarted="OnManipulationStarted"
        ManipulationDelta="OnManipulationDelta"
        ManipulationCompleted="OnManipulationCompleted"
        Stretch="None"
        ImageOpened="OnImageOpened">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <MatrixTransform x:Name="previousTransform" />
                <TransformGroup x:Name="currentTransform">
                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform" />
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform" />
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="translateTransform" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Canvas>
```

When i move image on the screen it's still possible to lose it. I use GetSquare to check the  remaining image square and if the square is very small i try to push the image back

```
private double GetSquare()
{
    Rect rect = Utils.GetBounds(Image, ImageCanvas);
    var canvasRect = RootGeometry.Rect;
    canvasRect.Intersect(rect);
    return canvasRect.Height * canvasRect.Width;
}

double maxSquare=30000;
double allowedSquare=40000;

private void OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double square = GetSquare();

    if (square < maxSquare || double.IsInfinity(square))
    {
        e.Complete();

        int counter = 0;

        while (GetSquare() <= allowedSquare)
        {
            counter++;

            translateTransform.X -= 100 * e.Velocities.Linear.X;
            translateTransform.Y -= 100 * e.Velocities.Linear.Y;

            if (counter > 10)
            {  
                ToInitState();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        translateTransform.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        translateTransform.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
    }

    //Rotate
    rotateTransform.Angle += e.Delta.Rotation;

    //Scale
    double deltaScale = e.Delta.Scale;
    double newScale = Utils.GetImageCurrentScale(Image) * deltaScale;

    if (newScale < Utils.MAX_ZOOM && newScale > Utils.MIN_ZOOM)
    {
        scaleTransform.ScaleX *= deltaScale;
        scaleTransform.ScaleY *= deltaScale;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you set RootGeometry.Rect? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: RootGeometry it's the name of RectangleGeometry (Canvas). GetBounds method gives me the remaining visible square of image. Using this square i can define when i should stop transformation and return the image to the screen.